# Understanding Difference Between Data Filters in core service

Tags: 2013

We have Data filter in core service each having its own use,with difference Can any one having good blog to understand it,mostly getting confused with OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData and  RepositoryItemsFilterData..

1. OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData
2. CategoriesFilterData
3. RepositoryItemsFilterData
4. ProcessesFilterData
5. PublishTransactionsFilterData

Comment: this post given me some answer's http://www.curlette.com/?p=362 like RepositoryItemsFilterData  we used for publication filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wish you have done some self-study or R&D your self to get an answer to it.

A very brief introduction about them is as below and I would suggest you to further explore them yourself:

1. **OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData** - If you want to filter content with in a Folder, Structure Group, Virtual Folder etc.: Like getting a a list of components with in a specific folder or multimedia components based on a specific schema
2. **CategoriesFilterData** - If you want to filter category-keywords: Like getting all categories with in a publication
3. **RepositoryItemsFilterData** - If you want to filter content within the Publication: Like getting components and schema with in a Publication
4. **ProcessesFilterData** - Filtering Workflow processes: Like Getting all active workflow process initiated by a specific user
5. **PublishTransactionsFilterData** - If you want to filter Published Transactions: Like getting all Components and Pages published from a publication and got failed during the Publishing process.

I hope this helps you getting started with the core service and data filters.

Comment: how to differentiate SubjectWiserFilterData and SystemWideFilterData in retriveing data from core service....

Comment: The SystemWideFilterData is a base class of filterdata being used in the GetSystemWideList method of core api. Few filters inheriting this class are PublishTransactionsFilterData, UsersFilterData  etc.

Regarding SubjectWiserFilterData I never have used or heard about it

Comment: sorry it is Tridion.ContentManager.Data.SubjectRelatedListFilterData not SubjectWiserFilterData

Comment: This is the base class from which most of the filters you have asked and I have described above are inherited

Comment: will selection of data filter's affect performance in extensions?????? eg. if i implemented same extension using SystemWideFilterData and SubjectRelatedListFilterData.is it like that some filter bringing more xml data as a response or other bringing less xml data in response(consider Data extender's).......And thanks for positive response

Comment: Just raise a separate question and explain what you want to do, what you have tried so far what is the issue you are facing....and the entire community will be happy to help